# How to rollback a transaction declared in store procedure which is already committed, when outer transaction from JDBC get rollback

Tags: java, jdbc

Currently I am facing a scenario, I have opened a transaction in JDBC and than I am calling a store procedure using prepared statement , there is also a transaction and its commit in store procedure after calling the store procedure and some other calls I commit the JDBC transaction. Now I want when Outer JDBC transaction get Rollback , also the inner transaction of store procedure should be rollback which is already committed.
Do any body have idea about this. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: When something is comitted, it's comitted and done with. You cannot rollback a comitted transaction. If you need that, then don't commit in the stored procedure

Comment: The horse is right; committed is committed. Though, for use cases like yours, relational database drivers sometimes offer save points, that allow you to save the state of an inner transaction that can be rolled back on its own, without rolling back the outer transaction. Looking into save point support for your driver might help.

Comment: Unless your database really supports nested transactions, which some do, this won't work.

Comment: Basically I don't have any control on store procedure, is there any transaction propagation mechanism that if the out transaction fails and get rollback, than inner transactions even it is committed should also be rollback

Comment: I am working on a product that supports, oracle, mysql, postgres and SQL server so will that be possible for these databases

Comment: All of these databases do not support Savepoints.  However, PostgreSQL, for example, does...  If you need to support all of these databases the same way, you may need to rethink the strategy

Answer (score 0):

Transaction boundary propagation across a JDBC bridge in this case is not possible. Commit is a commit like a_horse_with_no_name and  and EJP mentioned.